# Can every elements in a C*-algebra be expressed by infinite series of generators?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra with self-adjoint generators $x$ and $y$. Can every element in $A$ be expressed by infinite series of powers of $x$ and $y$? i.e. if $a\in A$, then $a$ is infinite sum of $x, y, x^{2}, xy, yx ,y^{2},...$.

I thought that is possible since algebra generated by generators is dense in $A$, but someone told me it is not the case. If not, what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you say were true, every continuous function would be analytic.

Concretely, let $A=C\big(\overline{\mathbb D}^2\big)$, the continuous functions on two complex variables on the closed unit bidisk. The operators you postulate, that is series of the form
$$
g(z,w)=\sum_{k,j=0}^\infty c_k\,z^k w^j,
$$
are the analytic functions on two variables. But there exist (many) continuous functions which are not analytic, starting with $f(z)=\overline z$, all the way to nowhere differentiable functions.

This does not change the fact that (due to Stone-Weierstrass) every continuous functions is a uniform limit of polynomials. What the above means is that in general you cannot choose the sequence polynomials converging to $f$ to be the partial sums of a series.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can an element be expressed in infinite sum of polynomial instead? And the degree of polynomials are increasing?

Comment: Yes, but it's kind of meaningless. If $x=\lim_n x_n$ and $x$ is not a polynomial, then the degrees of the polynomials have to grow to infinity. Choosing a subsquence, you can get the degrees to be monotone. Now write $x=x_1+\lim_n\sum_{k=1}^n x_{k+1}-x_k$. I don't think you can expect to obtain absolutely any information from this. For instance consider $C[0,1]$. Take the Cantor function, or the Weierstrass M-function, or the most crazy non-dfferentiable continuous functions out there. They are all of the form you want.